# elementary OS on MacBook Pro (2009) missing brightness control

Tags: release-juno, nvidia, brightness

After clean install and update of graphics driver (Nvidia), I have no brightness control in elementary OS. I have seen elementary OS on another system and it has brightness in the menu bar.

Why don't I have one? I also don't have brightness in my settings.

After searching through this board, I found a few responses but no definitive answers.

Comment: How did you install the nvidia drivers? Did you install them from Appcenter?

Comment: It seems this problem is by no means exclusive to elementary OS (they rarely are) have a look here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2336728

Comment: Yes I installed it from appcenter. It was under the "tab" installed and showed suggested driver for nvidia.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `lspci -v |grep VGA`. I want to be sure about what video card model you have.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is what it came up with: 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C79 [GeForce 9400M] (rev b1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])